# setting switch view state to checked based on database value android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-switch

i have just started learning android today, and so far i am going good, but getting an issue while changing the state of switch view dynamically. i have given a option in setting to check updates, so that user can on or off it as per their choice..

i am trying to set the state of switch view to checked or unchecked based on the last selected option of user which is stored in a database, the code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchupdates);

    taskkeeperdb = new DbHelper(this, "taskkeeper", null, 1);
    db = taskkeeperdb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from tblsettings", null);
    System.out.println("Cursore Created");
    if (result != null) {
        System.out.println("While Block");
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("inside while block");
            String name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("title"));
            String value = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("value"));
            System.out.println("values are in variable");
            switch (name) {
            case "check_updates":
                System.out.println("check updae case");
                if (value == "YES") {
                    //sw.setText("Check for Updates: On");
                    sw.setChecked(true);
                    System.out.println("YESYESYESYESYESYESYESYESY");
                } else {
                    //sw.setText("Check for Updates: Off");
                    sw.setChecked(false);
                    System.out.println("NONONONONONONONONON");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ending the if block.....");
    }
    if (!result.isClosed()) {
        result.close();
    }
    sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}
```

updating table when user interact with the switch view toggle.....

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = taskkeeperdb.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    if (isChecked) {
        cv.put("value", "YES");
        db.update("tblsettings", cv, "title='check_updates'", null);
        sw.setText("Check for Updates: On");
        cv.clear();
    } else {
        cv.put("value", "NO");
        db.update("tblsettings", cv, "title='check_updates'", null);
        sw.setText("Check for Updates: Off");
        cv.clear();
    }
}
```

now when i open the setting view it does not reflect the changes..
and in my console the `system.out.println` only shows:

`12-12 13:11:59.810: I/System.out(23320): Cursore Created`

`12-12 13:11:59.810: I/System.out(23320): While Block`

`12-12 13:11:59.820: I/System.out(23320): ending the if block.....`

my DbHelper code:

```
public DbHelper(Context context, String databaseName,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists tblsettings (id integer primary key autoincrement, title text, value text);");
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from tblsettings", null);
    //when no rows then insert fresh rows..
    if (result.getCount() == 0) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("title", "check_updates");
        contentValues.put("value", "NO");
        db.insert("tblsettings", null, contentValues);
    }
    if (!result.isClosed()) {
        result.close();
    }
}
```

as i am new i am not able to understand what may be the real reason.. 
please help thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to me, you've got a valid table named tblsettings with no rows in it.

Comment: please check i have updated the question with DbHelper where databse and table creation take place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks everyone, well i have solved the issue, the solution is just a minor mistake..

by changing the value comparison from `==` to `value.toString().equals("YES")` in the check_updates `switch case` i got what i was looking for.. the updated `switch case` is now:

```
switch (name) {
 case "check_updates":
         if (value.toString().equals("YES")) {
            sw.setText("Check for Updates: On");
            sw.setChecked(true);
         } else {
             sw.setText("Check for Updates: Off");
             sw.setChecked(false);
         }
         break;
 default:
         break;
            }
```